# CSS3 Transition won't trigger on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a fairly basic index page with various different links to reports. These links are a divs with an image inside of them, some text, and rounded corners. At the moment the background of the div changes color on hover. I wanted to add a Transition to make them pop out a bit on hover. The execs love stuff like that. However, it doesn't seem to want to take

```css
.card {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: .5%;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
}

.card:hover {
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  background-color: #b9d6a0;
  color: black;
}

.card>img {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 85%;
}

.dashboardlink {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card">
      <a href="/ip" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/ip.png" alt="Immediate Pays">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">Immediate Payments</p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <a href="/ipmtd" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/ipmtd.png" alt="Immediate Pays - MTD">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">Immediate Payments Month-To-Date</p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <a href="/ivrPayments" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/ivrPayments.png" alt="IVR Payments">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">IVR Payments</p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <a href="/outboundHold" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/outboundHold.png" alt="Outbound Holds">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">Outbounds Holds</p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <a href="/poolPen" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/PoolPen.png" alt="Pool Penetration">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">Pool Penetration</p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <a href="/Tracker" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/Tracker.png" alt="Tracker">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">Tracker Dashboard</p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <a href="/userLookup" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/userLookup.png" alt="User Lookup">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">SCSI User Lookup</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <a href="/inventory" target="_blank">
        <img class="dashboardlink" src="/images/inventory.png" alt="Inventory">
      </a>
      <p class="card-text">Inventory</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I am a bit new to CSS animations in general, and I'm in the process of tidying up a bootstrap template I used to build this page. Any advice would be appreciated to help polish or streamline what I'm trying to do.

Here's a screenshot of what the links look like on the page now:
[image]

The links to go ShinyDashboard Apps, but this page is just HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This may require some minor edits depending on your preference, but place the transition property in the .card class with the original size.  Then remove the transition property from .card:hover and add the new size there.  This link may help:  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```
.card {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: .5%;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}

.card:hover {
  width: (insert new size as needed)
  background-color: #b9d6a0;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what exact output you expect but something as simple as transitioning in/out background should work in your case.

[example](http://jsbin.com/xaxotexefo/edit?html,css,output)

```
transition: width 2s, height 2s;
```

this rule here makes no sense, transition prepares an element to animate it's properties smoothly, if you wanted to animate `width` or `height`, you should be doing transitioning width/height from 0 to some value but that's not specified in your code

Comment: I see. I was misreading the Transitions page, and thought the transition made the animation depicted at the top here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp, which is sort of what I'm trying to accomplish.